# String to integer conversion giving wrong output

Tags: c, function

I was solving the time conversion problem in hackerrank using call by value of C language.
However, I am unable to get my desired output.
This was my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void timeConversion(int,int,int,char*);

int main()
{
    char t[2];
    int hh,mm,ss;
    scanf("%02d:%02d:%02d%s",&hh,&mm,&ss,t);
    
    timeConversion(hh,mm,ss,t);
    return 0;
}
void timeConversion(int hour,int min,int sec, char *m)
{
    if(strcmp(m,"PM")==0 && hour!=12)
    hour+=12;
    if(strcmp(m,"AM")==0 && hour==12)
    hour=0;
    
    printf("%02d:%02d:%02d",hour,min,sec);
}
```

After running the code with the following input:

```
07:05:45PM
```

The output should have been:

```
19:05:45
```

However my output was:

```
12:05:45
```

When I tried to test run my code with the same input but including a printf statements to see the argument of the function in  the function definition:

```
void timeConversion(int hour,int min,int sec, char *m)
{
    printf("%d %d %d \n",hour,min,sec);         //Added this
    if(strcmp(m,"PM")==0 && hour!=12)
    hour+=12;
    if(strcmp(m,"AM")==0 && hour==12)
    hour=0;
    
    printf("%02d:%02d:%02d",hour,min,sec);
}
```

This is what i got:

```
Input (stdin)
07:05:45PM

Your Output (stdout)
0 5 45 
12:05:45
```

So it can be seen that 7 of 07 and 0 of 05 is omitted.

**Why am i getting it like this, please provide the solution**

Answer (score 2):

Strings in C are terminated by null-character.

`char t[2];` can store only upto 1-character string (plus 1 terminating null-character) and the entered string `PM` is too long to store in that.

Allocate enough elements like `char t[3];`

Comment: It worked fine after allocating 3 elements. Thanks a lot